# How to shift focus of RTS gameplay from manual dexterity to strategy?

Tags: game-design, rts, strategy, board-game

I am doing an exercise where I have to make a board game where the win condition relates to area control. I decided to make a real-time game where players have to control certain key points at the end of each round.

The player gets a large amount of pawns as troops that they can move around to capture territory with. A big problem that I encountered was that players felt that dexterity played too much of a role in the game, and wanted to focus more on the strategic aspect. I agree with this sentiment.

I am looking for a solution to this problem in RTS games, since these games also deal with a large amount of troops that move around a big map.

I understand that it's incredibly difficult to provide an immediate solution without all the details, so I am looking for books and articles that break down troop control in RTS games.

Comment: I'm sorry to disappoint you, but on a competitive esport level, almost all the popular RTS games rely mostly on manual dexterity. Those few which do not, rely on the computer being able to automate most low-level decisions, which probably does not transfer to a board game.

Comment: @Philipp I hate how snobby this is going to sound, but do you happen to have a source for the reliance on manual dexterity. It would be great if I have something more official to reference than a comment

Comment: To me, _I have to make a board game_ does not match the concept of _real-time_ in "RTS".

Comment: @Vaillancourt did you read the second sentence?

Comment: @Professionalsocialoutcast The performance of high-level players in RTS games is often measured in [actions per minute](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Actions_per_minute). Common wisdom is that whoever can perform more (meaningful) actions per minute will usually have the edge in a competitive match.

Comment: @Philipp Thanks you very much, this helps a lot!

Comment: As a counter point about RTS board game feasibility, there is an official [StarCraft Board](https://boardgamegeek.com/boardgame/22827/starcraft-board-game) & it won an Origin award. Some things transfer more easily to video games than board games, but it still comes down to designing for experience & finding mechanics that support the theme &/or source material.

Comment: That said, this is a fairly vague, high level question. Rather than asking what things have more strategy than dexterity dependence, it would help if there were more details about the specific mechanics that were tried. It's not clear how the existing game relied on dexterity or what game play decisions were required. It's hard to offer suggestions for improvement without knowing the initial game design state.

Comment: @Pikalek my original question was edited, I am not asking for anyone to tell me the solution, I am looking for books / articles that break down the ways players control their troops in RTS games. I completely understand that without knowing the game or the data it's impossible for you to provide a solution

Comment: What we do here is ask & offer solutions. Getting lists of existing resources (books, links to other sites) is handled by a different website, called a search engine. I edited your question to keep it on-topic for this site, so that it would not be closed as off-topic.

Comment: @DMGregory I have already scoured a significant part of the web through my search engine with very little results, so I asked in the most relevant forum I could find. I would appreciate it if you keep this topic open so that it shows up in search engines in the future. This way it will be easier to find the stuff that I and anyone in the future might be looking for

Comment: I will not override the community's votes if they choose to down-vote or close this question for being off-topic. Answers that are just a link or name-drop to an external resource age poorly, as links rot and newer resources make old ones outdated.
 For this reason, StackExchange sites focus on questions that can be answered substantially in the body of a post (with links as supporting evidence but not the sole content). I offered you a way to frame this question that fits with this site's policies and norms, but if you choose not to use that advice then that's up to you.

Comment: @Pikalek I found a PDF for the manual of that game (although not in English) and according to those it is a turn-based game, not a real-time game. Mechanically speaking it doesn't really seem to have anything to do with the Starcraft computer game. It only uses the brand and the scenario.

Comment: @Philipp Yes it is turn based. It keeps some other design choices from the video game (asymmetric factions, tech trees, area control, exhaustible resources). There are board games with real time mechanics, so I think there's enough evidence to suggest it's doable. I also concede that if OP wants real time mechanics first & for most (as opposed to the *feel* of the RTS genre) than my example doesn't match those expectations.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because as written/reverted, it is a request for resources. These questions tend to attract open-ended lists of answers, where no one necessarily ranks as "correct," and the answers age poorly as links rot and old resources go out of date. While appropriate for the [Game Ddev Stack Exchange chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/19/game-development) or forum such as GameDev.net, it is not a good fit for the Stack Exchange Q&A model.

Answer (score 1):

The game [Eufloria](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eufloria) (called Dyson during development) had an interesting solution to this.

A Eufloria game map is a graph of circular nodes connected by traversable edges. Each node controlled by a player (by planting a tree on it) passively produces "seedling" units at some rate, which orbit that node until given an order.

The player cannot issue commands to individual seedlings, only plant them in bulk to make a new tree, or send *all* seedlings from one node to a neighbouring node.

This coarse granularity of commands, combined with the relatively slow movement of the seedlings, effectively removes high-dexterity "micro" play from the game, and all decision-making focuses on the broad-scale distribution of troops across the nodes of your territory and its immediate frontier.

Of course, this is easier in a video game where you can have a computer that can move all the little units to follow the high-level command, without the player needing to do it manually. But I think it has lessons you can apply:

- Focus on groups of units. Rather than moving large numbers of pawns, could you use a die or a token with a spinning counter to represent a group of units? Turn the die/spinner to account for the size of the group changing, and move it as a single object, rather than needing to manipulate many pieces.

  Your combat rules then hinge on the sizes of the group tokens involved, rather than pairwise interactions between every opposed unit.
- Discretize your space. Moving from one strategic position to another should involve just one or a few distinct hops, so the physical labour of moving pieces from one to the next is minimized.

I think the real-time nature of your game may also be a risk here. As long as the player who moves the fastest has an advantage, that will always push players to the limit of their dexterity to try to capitalize on that potential.

If you don't want to go full turn-based, consider making the game play out in rounds, where each round is still real-time, but players have a limited number of actions they can perform (and some mechanism to help them track this in the heat of the moment). If I know I can do just three things in the next interval, I'm encouraged to deliberate more, rather than rushing to act as fast as I can and course-correct by squeezing in more actions through pure dexterity. It also gives moments of rest so players aren't constantly running full-tilt, and can take in the strategic landscape, or talk a new player through the next step of learning the game.

Comment: This is indeed a very interesting solution, and one that a friend of mine doing the same exercise has already implemented. This solution was criticized by everyone that played his game since it was too confusing, and his game was turn based.
This solution will also not work for me since I have a mechanic that requires that players tactically leave pawns behind to form a line, so moving entire groups is not an option.    
Do you maybe have an article or book that breaks this game down that I could look at?
(sorry for bad formatting, i tried)

Comment: You'll find it's hard to get solutions that honour constraints you have not told us about in your question. Try editing your question to detail the current mechanics of your game, and try to reflect on which ones you're willing to change versus which should be considered hard constraints.

Comment: I will revert your changes, since you changed the thing that I am actually looking for. I do not expect anyone here to be able to give me a viable solution right off the bate. I came here looking for books and articles that could do that. You removed this line from my original post

Comment: *"I came here looking for books and articles that could do that"* such question wont be answerable and will be closed according to GDSE rules.